# Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK is not working for next month

Tags: android

**I really need an help here...**

The user is picking date using DatePickerDialog. I am trying to get the Day Of Week for the date that the user is picking.

I have the following code:

```
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
    Calendar startDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    startDate.setTime(date);
    int dayOfWeek = startDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    Log.i("ZCF", "Date  = " + dateFormat.format(date));
    Log.i("ZCF", "Day of Week: " + dayOfWeek );
```

the results are OK for any date that i am choosing in Jan 2019:

Example #1:

I/ZCF: Date  = 13/01/2019
    Day of Week: 1

Example #2:

I/ZCF: Date  = 25/01/2019
    Day of Week: 6

Example #3:

I/ZCF: Date  = 31/01/2019
    Day of Week: 5

**BUT when i am picking a date for other month than Jan 2019, i am getting wrong result!**

here are few examples:

Example #1:

I/ZCF: Date  = 01/02/2019
    Day of Week: 3

1-FEB-2019 is actually **Friday** and not **Tuesday** !

Example #2:

I/ZCF: Date  = 05/02/2019
    Day of Week: 7

5-FEB-2019 is actually is actually **Tuesday** and not **Saturday**

Example #3:

I/ZCF: Date  = 17/04/2019
    Day of Week: 5

17-APR-2019 is actually **Wednesday** and not **Thursday**

Can someone please explain me what i am doing wrong???

Comment: How are you figuring `date`? The pattern you have for the `SimpleDateFormat` in the posted snippet is wrong – months are uppercase `M`, not lowercase `m` – but that's not involved in getting your `dayOfWeek` value.

Comment: `GregorianCalendar` might be the correct class for such calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually the wrong format 'mm' is the problem...i have formatted the the date as follow:

```
                    Date date= new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy").parse(startDateString);
```

so the result was that formatted date got value ZERO for the month and actually i always got the Day Of Week of Jan-2019.

Thanks for the help.